# How to overwrite my sit branch based on a tag from Main branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs, devops, git-branch

I'm using Azure Devops server 2020.

Part of my maintanence task activity, need to overwrite a content in sit branch based on a tag from a main branch.

```
Eg: my main branch is tagged as below
1.0.3 --> current and latest
1.0.2 
1.0.1
```

I have a sit branch on same repo, i would like to overwrite my sit branch with 1.0.2 tag from main branch.

Any suggestions please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwirting a branch with another (or a tag) is typically done with `git reset`

From your `sit` branch, with a clean working tree, just do

```
$ git reset --hard 1.0.3
```

An advantage of this (rather than deleting and recreating the branch) is to keep the branch's reflog (you won't overwrite its past positions history).

(*Note :

If the branch had already been pushed to a remote, you'll need to push with `--force` to overwrite the remote ref as well.*)

Comment: steps:
- checkout: test@sit
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Overwrite SIT branch
  inputs:
    script: |
      git reset --hard 1.0.3
      git add .
      git commit -m "test commit"
      git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push --force http://10.0.0.4/ZZZZZZZ/YYYYYYY/_git/Test
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.repository.localpath)/' is it a right step?

Comment: No. The add+commit phase *after* the `reset` is useless, there won't be any changes here since we just resetted. And I can't speak for the "outside" stuff, whatever is outside the git commands is beyond my own scope.

Comment: Noted let me check and update

Answer (score 0):

You may delete your current sit (and before that create a backup sit branch if you need it). Then create a new sit branch from your tag: [Create branch from a tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-tags?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#create-branch-from-a-tag).

Comment: Thanks  a lot. is the below command looks fine?                                                           - task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Overwrite SIT branch
  inputs:
    script: |
      git push origin --delete sit
      git checkout -b test 1.0.3